# YouTube Player quality settings function leads to native code

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have traced the callback for setting the video quality on YouTube to native code, which means that it is code compiled from C/C++, right?

When I invoke the function the quality gets set properly but dumping the function to the console leads me to native code.

How to debug/disassemble/view source of the listener?

[image]

Comment: looks like it points to *Node.prototype.addEventListener* , so no way.

Comment: When I invoke the function the player switches quality properly, as if I called a simple function.

Comment: maybe they set the function.toString method. I do not know without having any code...